# Calls to GPU kernel from a multithreaded C++ application?

Tags: c++, multithreading, cuda, pthreads

I'm re-implementing some sections of an image processing library that's multithreaded C++ using pthreads. I'd like to be able to invoke a CUDA kernel in every thread and trust the device itself to handle kernel scheduling, but I know better than to count on that behavior. Does anyone have any experience with this type of issue?

Comment: There is only one link to the gpu, so I believe sending multiple things in the same time will be more a problem probably with the operating system than with the gpu. the only easy way this will work is using different processes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUDA 4.0 made it much simpler to drive a single CUDA context from multiple threads - just call cudaSetDevice() to specify which CUDA device you want the thread to submit commands.

Note that this is likely to be less efficient than driving the CUDA context from a single thread - unless the CPU threads have other work to keep them occupied between kernel launches, they are likely to get serialized by the mutexes that CUDA uses internally to keep its data structures consistent.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps Cuda streams are the solution to your problem. Try to invoke kernels from a different stream in each thread. However, I don't see how this will help, as I think that your kernel executions will be serialized, even though they are invoked in parallel. In fact, Cuda kernel invocations even on the same stream are asynchronous by nature, so you can make any number of invocations from the same thread. I really don't understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: On a single stream, invocations are asynchronous as far as the host is concerned, but are synchronous to the GPU (everything is executed in order, and one operation must finish before the next begins).  This goes for memory operations, as well as kernel launches.  In a single stream, you can't overlap/interleave memory operations with computations.  Multiple streams can overlap, which is where the potential advantage comes from. See here for more info (section on Streams and Async API): http://mc.stanford.edu/cgi-bin/images/0/0a/M02_4.pdf